# Oracle Golden Gate for HANA target

Tags: database-replication, hana, oracle-golden-gate

We have Oracle as source and HANA and Hadoop as data warehouse. We wanted to replicate Oracle data to HANA and Hadoop on real-time basis.

Golden gate has excellent integration with Hadoop components and Oracle.

Is it possible to replicate Oracle to HANA with Golden Gate. Is there better tool to use for this scenario.

Answer (score -1):

While I don't know about the Oracle Golden Gate capabilities in this regard, **[SAP HANA Smart Data Integration (SDI)](https://help.sap.com/viewer/p/HANA_SMART_DATA_INTEGRATION)** provides the option to replicate data from a number of RDBMS including Oracle to SAP HANA.

This is facilitated via the [Oracle Log Reader-Adapter](https://help.sap.com/viewer/7952ef28a6914997abc01745fef1b607/2.0_SPS03/en-US/ec2c46f0bf7047339e2acba050492941.html) which uses the Oracle LogMiner interface.

SAP HANA also offers the option to access data in Oracle "virtually", so that the data is not permanently stored in SAP HANA but queried from the source system at query runtime. This can be a more flexible and lightweight option than actually copying over data across.
This feature is called **[Smart Data Access](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_crm700_ehp03/7.0.3.11/en-US/bb/df686dc0d94f779b5c11d06753da95/frameset.htm)**.

Comment: Thank you Lars. SDI has very less flexibility and it's HANA specific solution only. We had already used SAP(Sybase) replication server  in some places but it has lot of inherent problems and I suppose SDI is based on same

Comment: My answer just pointed out an option to achieve the replication you asked about, but not to replace a generic generell data integration solution. If that’s what you’re after, you better update the question accordingly.